# Is the absolute value of Brownian motion a super martingale?Is it a sub martingale? Is it a Markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I've just started to study random processes and I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $W(t)$ be a Brownian motion with filtration $F(t)$ generated by  $ W(t)$ (i.e., $F(t)=\sigma \left( W(s)\right) $, $s \in [0,t]$).

- Is the process $|W(t)|$ a sub martingale? A super martingale? Or neither?
- Is $|W(t)|$ a Markov process?

Unfortunately, I can't see how to do that using the definition of sub/super martingale..
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use Jensens inequality for the absolute value function.

Comment: Conditional Jensen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties

Comment: To rule out the other, being both a sub and super martingale implies being a martingale.  What would $E[|W(t)|]$ be if $|W(t)|$ were a martingale? What would that imply?  I would give a hint about the Markov property, but it depends on what definition you're using.

Comment: @Chris Janjigian Jensen inequality for conditional expectations yields $|E[W(t)|F(s)]| \le E[|W(t)||F(s)]$. Thus, since $W(t)$ is a martingale, the left side is equal to $|W(s)|$. So finally, I have the following inequality: $E[|W(t)||F(s)] \ge |W(s)|$ - which tells that |W(t)| is submartingale. Answering your question - if |W(t)| was martingale then $E[|W(t)||F(s)] = |W(s)|$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian The definition of Markov process that I have is: Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space. Let T be a fixed positive number and let $F(t)$, $0\le t\le T$ be a filtration. Consider an adapted stochastic process $X(t)$, $0 \le t \le T$. Assume that for all $0 \le s \le t \le T$ and for every nonnegative Borel-measurable function $f$, there is another Borel-measurable function $g$ such that $E[f(X(t))|F(s)] = g(X(s))$. Then we say that X is a Markov process.

Comment: The hint was about the unconditional expectation $E[|W(t)|]$, not the conditional expectation.  For the Markov property, notice that the filtration generated by $|W(t)|$ is a strict subset of the filtration generated by $W(t)$.  Think about the tower rule.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian In the definition of martingale the process is required to have finite unconditional expectation, so if we assume $|W(t)|$ - martingale, then $E[|W(t)|] < \infty$ should be true. On the other hand, I can show that $E[|W(t)|] = \sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}$ which tends to $\infty$ as $t \to \infty$. Thus the process is not martingale, and it proves that it is only a submartingale. Is that what your hint supposed me to do?

Comment: That does not show that the process is not a martingale.  It's perfectly fine if the expectations diverge as $t \to \infty$.  My hint was this.  If it were a martingale, then you would have $0 = E[|W(0)|] = E[|W(t)|]$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Could you please explain me why  $0=E[|W(0)|]=E[|W(t)|]$ if my process was s martingale?

Comment: If $|W(t)|$ were a martingale, what would $E[|W(t)| | \mathcal{F}_0]$ be?  Then $E[|W(t)|] = E[E[|W(t)| | \mathcal{F}_0]] = \dots$

Answer (score 1):

Concerning you first question, $|W|$ is a submartingale:

In general if $X$ is a martingale and $\phi: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a convex funtion such that $\mathbb E[\phi(X_t)] < \infty$, then a simple application of the conditional Jensen's inequality shows that
$$
\mathbb{E}\bigl[\phi(X_t)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr] \geq \phi \Bigl(\mathbb{E}\bigl[X_t\mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr] \Bigr) = \phi(X_s), \quad \text{a.s.}
$$
Hence, the process $(\phi(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale.

In your case $X=W$ and $\phi(x)=|x|$. It is easy to check that $\phi$ is convex and $E[|W_t|] < \infty$.  Therefore $|W|$ is a submartingale.

**Edit:** the last part is incorrect as pointed out in the comments.

Concerning the Markov Property just keep in mind that $x \mapsto |x|$ is a measurable function (because it is continuous). Therefore the Markov property of $W$ implies the Markov property of $|W|$.

Comment: It's not generally true that a measurable (or even continuous) function of a Markov process is a Markov process.  For example, take simple random walk $X_n$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $Y_n = f(X_n)$ where $f(-2) = 2$ and $f(x) = x$ otherwise.  Then $$1/2 = P(Y_3 = 3 \mid Y_2 = 2, Y_1 = 1) \ne P(Y_3 = 3 \mid Y_2 = 2, Y_1 = -1) = 0.$$

Comment: The "submartingale" bit is good, but this justification of the Markov property is very bad. Try it with $f(x)= \max \{0,x\}$, for fun.

Comment: uuu, yeah thank you for pointing that out, I made a silly mistake

Comment: @NateEldredge It is my understanding that the function needs only to be measurable and bounded to imply the Markov property. Would it be allowable to say $|B_t| _=^d \sup_{0 \le s \le t} B_s$  sup of continuous function over finite interval is bounded, and sup B_s is measurable. So by the Markov property $|B_t|$ is Markov.  I don't like it because it seems to be pulling at the ear with the wrong hand but I am weak at maths so cant see how to do it otherwise.

Comment: @Novice: That really doesn't make any sense to me.  I would suggest that you try to give a precise statement of the theorem you are trying to use, and then see whether its hypotheses are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

To show the Markov property there is a direct approach.

Let $u \in \mathcal{B}_b(\mathbb{R})$, and $s,t \ge 0$. Then by the independent and stationary increment properties of BM:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | \mathcal{F_s}] &= \mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}-B_s +B_s|)| \mathcal{F_s}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}u(|B_{t+s}-B_s +y|)\bigg|_{y=B_s}\\
&= \mathbb{E}u(|B_t +y|)\bigg|_{y=B_s}
\end{align*}

By symmetry of BM we get that, for $g_t(z)$ normal denisty,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | \mathcal{F_s}] &= \frac{1}{2} \left[\mathbb{E}u(|B_t +y|)\bigg|_{y=B_s} + \mathbb{E}u(|B_t -y|)\bigg|_{y=B_s} \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(u(|z+y|) + u(|z-y|)\right)g_t(z)dz \right]\bigg|_{y=B_s}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u(|z|)(g_t(z+y) + g_t(z-y))dz \right]\bigg|_{y=B_s}\\
&= \int_{0}^{+\infty}u(|z|)(g_t(z+y) + g_t(z-y))dz \bigg|_{y=B_s}
\end{align*}

The integral is independent of $s$. Hence $\mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | \mathcal{F_s}]$ is a function of $|B_s|$.

Thus

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | \mathcal{F_s}] = g(B_s)  
\end{equation*}

for some Borel function $g$.

It follows, by the tower property for conditional expectations, that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | X_s] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | \mathcal{F_s}|X_s\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[g(B_s)|X_s]\\
&=g(B_s).
\end{align*}

Hence we conclude that

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | \mathcal{F_s}] = \mathbb{E}[u(|B_{t+s}|) | X_s].
\end{equation*}

Thus $|B_t|$ is Markov.

Comment: There are some mismatched parentheses that make this hard to read.

Comment: Thanks Nate for the remark. Can you let me know if this is now correct. Best wishes.

Comment: The first two lines still look wrong, with the parentheses mismatched around the absolute values.

Comment: why can we have $$\mathbb{E}\Big[h(|W_{s+t}-W_{s}+W_{s}|)\ \Big|\ \mathcal{F}_{s}\Big]=\mathbb{E}h(|W_{s+t}-W_{s}+y|)\Big|_{y=W_{s}}?$$

Answer (score 0):

Markov property: The way I present here is direct but not quite simple. A simpler way of proving this is by using tower property and an observation that $\sigma(|B_s|, s\leq t) \subset \sigma(B_s, s\leq t)$.

Consider ${\cal{F}}_t := \sigma(|B_s|, s\leq t)$ and we will prove that for any $0< a < b$
$$ \mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ {\cal{F}}_s) = \mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ |B_s|). $$
We start by proving that the event $\{B_s > 0\}$ is independent of ${\cal{F}}_s$, similarly then $\{B_s < 0\}$ would be independent of ${\cal{F}}_s$. First consider $|B_s|$ and $\{B_s > 0\}$
$$ 
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}(|B_s| \in [a,b],\ B_s>0) &= \int_{[a, b]} p(s, 0, x) dx =  \frac1{2}\int_{[a, b]} p(s, 0, x) +p(s, 0, -x) dx \\
&= \mathbb{P}(B_s>0)\ \mathbb{P}(|B_s| \in [a,b]).
\end{split}
$$
Analogous equalities can be written for any sequence of times $0<s_1<\ldots <s_n=s$ (as long as the final time $s$ features in there) and any sequence of positive $\{a_i<b_i\}_{i\leq n}$
$$\mathbb{P}(\forall i\leq n \ |B_{s_i}| \in [a_i,b_i],\ B_s>0) = \mathbb{P}(\forall i\leq n \ |B_{s_i}| \in [a_i,b_i])\ \mathbb{P}(B_s>0),$$
thus showing that $\{B_s>0\}$ is independent of the sets that generate ${\cal{F}}_s$, see the definition of natural filtration e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_filtration).

Now consider the following: here $\ldots$ stands for the mirror expression with $B_s < 0$
$$ 
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ {\cal{F}}_s) &= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b], B_s > 0\ |\ {\cal{F}}_s) + \ldots \\
\text{[product law]}&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ {\cal{F}}_s, \ B_s > 0) \ \mathbb{P}(B_s > 0 \ |\ {\cal{F}}_s)  + \ldots \\
\text{[independence of $B_s>0$ and ${\cal{F}}_s$]}&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ {\cal{F}}_s, \ B_s > 0) \ \frac1{2}  + \ldots \\
\text{[knowing $B_s>0$ and ${\cal{F}}_s$ implies the value of $B_s$]}&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ {\cal{F}}_s, \ B_s, \ B_s > 0) \ \frac1{2}  + \ldots \\
\text{[Markov property of $B$ removes ${\cal{F}}_s$]}&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ B_s, \ B_s > 0) \ \frac1{2}  + \ldots \\
&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ |B_s|, \ B_s > 0) \ \frac1{2}  + \ldots \\
\text{[Bayes formula]}
&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b], \ B_s > 0\ |\ |B_s|) \ \frac{1/2}{\mathbb{P}(B_s > 0\ |\ |B_s|)}  + \ldots \\
\text{[independence of $B_s>0$ and $|B_s|$]}
&= 
\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b], \ B_s > 0\ |\ |B_s|) + \ldots \\
\text{[recombining the disjoint probabilities]}&=\mathbb{P}(|B_t| \in [a,b]\ |\ |B_s|).
\end{split}
$$